# Bash writing arguments using for loop

Tags: bash

I want for example write all arguments using for loop, when I write:

```
for (( i=1; $i <= $#; i++ )) ; do
    echo "${$i}"
done
```

or

```
echo "$$i"
```

it doesn't work. I can't also do loop:

```
for arg in "$@"
```

Because I want to have acces to next argument, if current is for example "-n". (My line of arguments will be e.g -n 10 -k 50 -s 4)

Comment: Use indirection `echo "${!i}"`.http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html. Also this is 100% a duplicate but i can't be bothered finding it if anyone else wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use getopts ?

```
while getopts ':n:k:s:' opt
do
case "$opt" in 
n) echo "option n with $OPTRARG"
   ;;
k) echo "option k with $OPTRARG"
   ;;
s) echo "option s with $OPTRARG"
   ;;
*) echo "Bad usage"
esac
done
```